# Events not being broadcasted in Laravel WebSocket Dashboard

Tags: laravel, websocket, laravel-websockets

I am experiencing a weird problem where my Laravel Websockets suddenly stopped. It was working on both HTTP and HTTPS fine a few days back.
The problem is, my Events are being fired but are not being broadcasted to the Laravel Websockets Dashboard.

Whenever someone logs on to my application, The presence online channel gets subscribed just fine

But the problem occurs when I try to fire an event from my code or by using the Event Creator from Websocket Dashboard

When fired from the Event Creator, the network tab shows "OK" but the event is not being broadcasted.

What could possibly be the reason? I haven't changed my code at all and it was working just fine but It just randomly stopped working

Comment: Debug your frontend code then if it is listening on correct channel with correct permissions

Comment: Please elaborate